# Py4JJava Error when i try to run a pyspark code

Tags: python, pyspark

[The above in the image is the code that i want to run. Actually the dataset is a TXT file and i want to calculate the no of repetitions of "CAG" from that dataset txt file. I'm always getting this error . Pls find me a way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHoIZ.png)

I have already tried some youtube videos and certain commands along with java and python versions

Answer (score 0):

The `createDataFrame` method expects an RDD, but `textFile` returns an RDD of strings. You need to convert each line to a tuple or a structure before creating the DataFrame.

```
# Convert each line to a tuple (or a structure of your choice)
sequences_rdd = sequences_rdd.map(lambda x: (x,))

# Create a DataFrame with a column named "text"
df = spark.createDataFrame(sequences_rdd, ["text"])
```